# How to connect models in a form without nesting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I did a lot of searches for this problem and watched quite a few tutorials (e.g railscast: nested model form) but I'm afraid it's not the right solution to my problem.

I want to collect data for a theory. This theory has many questions to be answered on distinctive cards. I always want to display all questions (on all cards), but the answers may vary, depending on each card. Therefor I need to catch the question_id and card_id, but deep nesting and catching the id by params would be quite a pain. Does anyone know a better solution for my problem?

Here are my models:

**theory.rb**

```
class Theory < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :cards
has_many :questions
```

**card.rb**

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :theory
has_many :answers
has_many :questions  (Do I need this here - I always want to display all questions?)
```

**question.rb**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :theory
has_many :answers
```

**answer.rb**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :card
belongs_to :question
```

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The relationships between your models should not be determined by how they will be displayed on the screen.  They should be determined by how they are actually related to each other.

I don't fully understand what theory/card are supposed to represent so I can't tell you what relationships need to exist, but I can have a stab at at it :

It seems to me as though a card represents the answers for a single person that relate a to a specific Theory?   If so, then you don't need the "has_many :questions" because the card only has answers.  Also, each answer links to a question so you can "get" to the questions through the answers.   You could add a "has_many :questions, :through=>:answers" to the Card model if you really wanted the list of questions for a card.

If each card can have a different set of questions added to it before any answering is done, then you will need the "has_many :questions", but if all the questions are on each card then you won't need it.

Update in response to your comments below :

One way is to add the answers to the card by building them up in the controller:

```
@card = Card.find 2
@theory = Theory.find 1

@theory.questions.each do |question|
   @card.answers.build :question=>question 
end
```

Then in your view do something like this (this is HAML) :

```
 = form_for @card do |f|
   -@card.answers.each do |answer|
     =f.fields_for answer do |answer_form|
       =answer_form.hidden_field :question_id 
       %p=answer.question.full_question 
       %p=answer_form.text_field :input
```

This is using nested form attributes, so to get it to work with your Card model you'll have to add this to it :

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
  ..
end
```

Comment: I know it sounds complicating, but what I want are cards, that all show the same questions, but different answers. (E.g. Theory is philosophy of rights and every card represents a philosopher and his individual answers to the same questions.) So a question has many answers through cards. But now practically, how do I get the question_id in my form? How can I connect the question field with the answer input-field?

Comment: I try to avoid accepts_nested_attributes_for, especially for fairly complex nestings.   It couples your view too tightly with your model.